# Credential for Release Signing SHA-1 on Google Sheets API not working

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I'm having problem with the credential made on Google API console for Sheets API using release signing SHA-1 from Play Store. I made 3 different credential for SHA-1 debug, release and release (that signed by Playstore). The debug and release credential works fine, but the credential using SHA-1 provided by Google Playstore return error 404 (it does not have access to the spreadsheet, I presume).

Note that all the SHA-1 and package name are correct.

I believe this has nothing to do with the code, but approval credential from Google.

1. Does Google have limitation on creating a credential (especially for OAuth 2.0)? I only made around 8 credentials/ client ID.
2. Does it took times for the credential to work? Because I just release the app on Playstore 3 days ago, the app is already live on Playstore tho.

What should I do? I try to directly contact Google API support but couldn't find any link/ reference to contact them.

Thank you in advance for those whom willing to help.

Comment: Typically when you publish an app, the Play Store will remove your APK and sign with its own.  So the key you need to specify in Google console is this signed key provided by the store, and _not_ your release local key.

Comment: Understand that, i used the key provide by the store tho and it still return 404 error. I got another app that uses the signed key provide by the store and it works fine.